# Clean run dialog suggestion in Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10

Recently, in Windows 10, whenever I bring up the run command, a lot of irrelevant suggestions are appearing. (Example at: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpA1b.png)

I'm aware that one can delete the run history in registry at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RunMRU` however none of these suggestions are in the mentioned registry location (Example, on the same machine at: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgqiF.png)

My question is: **What else do I need to clean in order for those suggestions not to appear?**

My goal would be, in the example above, that only `mspaint` should show up, as a suggestion

Comment: I believe you can use CCleaner to remove those.

Comment: @Davidw Okay, in that case: what does cc cleaner modifies for the desired results? I like to keep things clean and simple. I'd rather not modify the environment for this.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know how it works, in this case, only that it does.

Comment: If the entries appear when you start typing something, but not necessarily when you click the drop-down arrow, they probably come from Internet Explorer's history. Try clearing history in IE.

Comment: Nice tip but IE was used only once. (when I downloaded Chrome) so that's not the problem.